# No Fair Merge via Nondeterminstic Data Flow Streams

Tags: dc.parallel-comp, proofs

While reading Wikipedia, I ran across a proof given on [Unbounded Nondeterminism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unbounded_nondeterminism) that I do not understand.

The proof is given as,

> An example of the role of fair or unbounded nondeterminism in the merging of strings was given by William D. Clinger, in his 1981 thesis. He defined a "fair merge" of two strings to be a third string in which each character of each string must occur eventually. He then considered the set of all fair merges of two strings merge(S, T), assuming it to be a monotone function. Then he argued that merge(⊥,1<sup>ω</sup>)⊆ merge(0,1<sup>ω</sup>), where ⊥ is the empty stream. Now merge(⊥,1<sup>ω</sup>) = 1<sup>ω</sup>, so it must be that 1<sup>ω</sup> is an element of merge(0,1<sup>ω</sup>), a contradiction.

My misunderstanding is, "merge(⊥,1<sup>ω</sup>) = 1<sup>ω</sup>." Previously it said that "merge(S, T)" is "the set of all fair merges of two strings".

Why is "merge(⊥,1<sup>ω</sup>) = 1<sup>ω</sup>," instead of merge(⊥,1<sup>ω</sup>) = {1<sup>ω</sup>}. If so, isn't {1<sup>ω</sup>} ⊆  merge(0,1<sup>ω</sup>)? What am I missing?

Comment: Looks like a typo... "If merge(⊥,$1^ω$) = {$1^ω$} and merge(⊥,$1^ω$) $\subseteq$ merge(0,$1^ω$), then $1^ω$ is an element of merge(0,$1^ω$)." would appear to be the correct step in the proof.

Answer (score 4):

When in doubt, consult the original source: [Clinger's Thesis](http://dspace.mit.edu/handle/1721.1/6935). Clinger shows that fair merge cannot be written in a nondeterministic dataflow program. He does this by considering the semantic domains in which such a function would be defined, ultimately deriving a contradiction to the assumption that fair merge exists.

Firstly, as Daniel Apon points out, $merge(\bot,1^\omega)=\{1^\omega\}$. This is the only reasonable definition of merge for these arguments (see page 84 of Clinger's thesis).

Secondly, $merge(\bot,1^\omega)\subseteq merge(0,1^\omega)$, because  $\bot\le 0$, as stream $0$ is a possible extension of stream $\bot$ (bottom of page 73),  and by assumption $merge$ is monotone. In more detail, the ordering on the domain of strings states that any prefix of a string, is $\le$ the string, thus the empty string $\bot$ is the smallest element, and hence $\bot\le 0$, where $0$ is the string with just the element $0$. The function $merge$ has type $S\times S\to\mathcal{P}(S)$, where $S$ is string and $\mathcal{P}(-)$ is powerset.  The assumption that $merge$ is monotone means that if $a\le b$ then $merge(a,s)\subseteq merge(b,s)$. (Similarly for the second argument.)

Now $1^\omega\in merge(0,1^\omega)$ violates the assumption that $merge$ is fair – a fair merge of $0$ and $1^\omega$ should to contain the $0$. In more detail, $merge(S,T)$ is interleaving the "cards" from $S$ and $T$, without shuffling them. The significance of the stream $1^\omega$ is that it is infinite. $0$ is simply some character different from $1$. A fair merge of $0$ and $1^\omega$ should result in a string such as $1^*01^\omega$. Fairness means that within some finite time it selects elements from each string, thus the character $0$ is eventually chosen.

Hence $merge$ cannot be written as a nondeterministic dataflow program.

Comment: <p>Thanks, Dave Carke, I still do not understand why 1<sup>ω</sup> ∈ <i>merge</i>(0,1<sup>ω</sup>). The <i>merge</i>(S,T) is similar shuffling cards, if I understand correctly. Is there some special significance to either of the streams 0 or 1<sup>ω</sup>? </p>

Comment: I've expanded my answer. I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your patience Dave. It finally dawned on me, I haven't looked critically at a proof in a very long time; otherwise, I might have got it in the first place.

Comment: My pleasure, Edwin.